# After Effects Slider expression to increase or decrease visible layers

Tags: javascript, adobe, after-effects

As the slider number increases I want the layers visible in my comp to increase and visa-versa.

Expression I am using:

```
t = thisComp.layer("Control").effect("Slider Control")("Slider");
r = thisComp.layer("Control");
if (index - r.index == t) {100} else {0};
```

[Project screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eqh3W.png)

At the moment as you increase the Slider it reveals one layer at at time but I want all layers below the selected index number to stay visible until I lower the Slider amount.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I feel silly.  All I needed was to change equal to operator == to less than, or equal to <=.

```
t = thisComp.layer("Control").effect("Slider Control")("Slider");
r = thisComp.layer("Control");
if (index - r.index <= t) {100} else {0};
```

Now it works perfectly.